# CMake with Xcode 5 : how to add external libraries as 'Target Dependencies' instead of linker flags?

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, cmake

We are building our software under OS X (10.8 at the moment). The project build is managed by CMake (2.8.12).

External dependencies (i.e. not target added by project's *CMakeLists*) are handled using what we undestood as the canonical way :

- Calling `find_package(${external_lib})` from a root *CMakeLists*.
- If a given target needs to link against the previously found package, the target's *CMakeLists* calls `target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${${external_lib}_LIBRARIES})`

The procedure works nicely from a building perspective (the target is actually linked against the external library). Yet the external library is actually given as an additional flag to the compiler, in `Build Settings::Other Linker Flags`, when it seems that Xcode native way for doing this would be to add the **dirname** to `Build Settings::Library Search Path`, and the **basename** to `Build phases::Target Dependencies`.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior (without breaking the behavior for other platforms) ?

Comment: If the problem is to avoid breaking the default behaviour for other platform, the way I suggest is simply to add exceptions for OSX like: `if (APPLE) do something endif(APPLE)` . In almost any case you will need to add a few platform-specific rules to have your project biulding correctly. You will need some `if (WIN32)` and some `if (MVSC)` for sure... (and some `if(UNIX)` too btw...)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of CMake was changed years ago to use full paths.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0003.html

Why do you want to split it?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but it seems to me that the "split approach" is the canonical way to do it in Xcode (it has been done this way on most projects I have seen, where the .xcodeproj file was actually built inside Xcode). If this statement is right, it feels like it would be good to conform to other developers' expectations (making CMake acceptance easier, among other things).

Comment: CMake is almost certainly not going to change to a split approach. The canonical way with CMake is non-split, for reasons in the link I posted.